# Remove files periodically from Volume Mount in Kubernetes Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes pod running which has two containers, say A and B. They share  common volume of type `emptyDir`. I have a usecase in which application running in container A takes files uploaded by client and places them at mount point. Then it signals to container B to process the file. Container B then sends back response to A (The response is instantaneous and not batched). Now as the file is processed it can be deleted (It must be, due to obvious storage constraints). Deleting files one by one as they are processed could be lot of deletions (or not?) so thought of considering batch deletions periodically.

1. What is the best way to delete this file?
2. Is it good to use this volume type for this usecase? If not what?

```
# deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: FileProcessor
  labels:
    app: FileProcessor
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: FileProcessor
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: FileProcessor
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: processor:0.2
        name: Container_B
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: Container_B
        volumeMounts:
        - name: upload-files
          mountPath: /app/upload-files
      - image: sample:0.1
        name: Container_A
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: Container_A
        volumeMounts:
        - name: upload-files
          mountPath: /app/uploads
      volumes:
      - name: upload-files
        emptyDir: {}
```

PS: This is to be deployed on GKE.
Update 1: Still looking for a better solution

Comment: have you encountered any error/problem following your own ideas/design?

Comment: @LeiYang Not yet. But I feel it is bound to encounter errors. So looking for suggestions.

Comment: multiple pods sharing same files and modify/delete them is really error prone. should need some file locks at least. just think of how to handle when your pod scales/startup/terminates is quite complex.

Comment: No multiple pods wont be sharing same files. The volume mount is pod scoped. So only containers inside this pod can access or share files between them. And here container A is the sole uploader and container B is the sole consumer. So only after container B has processed the file, it can be deleted.

Comment: How does this application work if you want to scale it up, so you set `replicas: 5`?  What happens to the data if you update `image: processor: 0.3`?  (I'd recommend two separate Deployments here, and something outside Kubernetes like Google Cloud Storage for the actual data storage.)

Comment: Scaling doesn't effect anything as container B is stateless and only a helper container. So this is per pod. Also are you talking about the situation where when we update an image and due to rolling update old pods with files not processed may terminate and those files are lost? Yeah this is a concern now that I think about it. Thanks. Why would we need two separate deployments and are they old and new versions?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `emptyDir`, files must be deleted from one of the sidecars. Now, lets check what are your options here:

1. Container A or B can delete the files after processing them.
2. Container A or B delete the files once they reach a certain amount (say 1Gi).
3. Add another container C which periodically cleanup the files.

Now, lets check advantage and disadvantage of these solutions:

- If you go with solution 1, your container A or B will have to do little extra work after each processing. If the files size are not large enough this extra time shouldn't be significant
- If you go with solution 2, you might save extra work after each processing. However, after a certain period container A or B will require a relatively long time to cleanup those files. Furthermore, you have to add logic when to cleanup the files. If you can do it intelligently, let say when your containers are idle, then this solution should fit best.
- Now, if you go with solution 3, you have to ensure that your container C   does not delete files that are being processed by container B.

In case, you want to use a different type of volume, which can be mounted from an external pod, then you can have a CronJob to periodically cleanup those data. In this case, same constraint of solution 3 is applicable.

Comment: Do you have an example where it is done intelligently? Also for solution 3, thinking of deleting based on creation time(like files created before 10 mins). So a cronjob would run to do this task every 10mins

Comment: No. I don't have such example. Yes, you can have an external CronJob to delete data that are older than X min periodically.

Comment: As stated by @David Maze in the comments above, we would still have a problem with this approach like files which are not more than 10 mins old wont be processed :(